# Android i wrote download mp3 file from server some error in my code

Tags: java, android, save, mp3

Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/sura-001.mp3 (Permission denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help from the below url

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301577/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied)

http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/java-io-filenotfoundexception-with-permission-denied/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

check if permissions are added or not...

**Updated::**

This is how your manifest file should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.com.com"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>   
</manifeast>
```

Comment: if above wont solves your issue then either try by changing file name which contains no special characters or use Environment.getExternalStorageState() to refer to external directory if you had hard coded the path.